# Error "expression result unused" when using comma operator

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the comma **Operator** in C and I have encountered this compilation error. Can somebody help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = (1,2);
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

I am using a GCC compiler.
I expect the variable "a" value to equal 2 and print it out as output by the printf. But the following warning is generated.

Output:

```
test.c:5:11: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        int a = (1,2);
                 ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: Why do you think that's an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)

Comment: "*I expect a value to equal 2 and print it out in the next line*". You'll never get that from the compiler output. You need to run the binary that the compiler produces. Did you do that? Please show your exact commands.

Comment: @ Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica. I expect it to store a = 2.

Comment: @kaylum I did,  "gcc test.c". Do i need to do something else?

Comment: Yes. That will produce a default `a.out` binary. Run with `./a.out`. Please consider reading a good C book or tutorial as this should be covered in any such reference material.

Comment: @kaylum   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comna-in-c-and-c/. I expect this to happen. Assign value of 2 to variable a.

Comment: What about the previous comment?? Did you manage to [run it](https://ideone.com/O5lTrH)? Your code does do that. You just need to run it properly to see it. The compiler is just telling you that you are throwing away the `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler is configured to treat warnings as being fatal. Normally it is not a good idea to disable that but for this experimental case you can disable it with `-Wno-error`.

```
$ gcc -Wno-error test.c
test.c:9:14: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    int a = (1,2);
             ^
1 warning generated.
$ ./a.out
2
```

Comment: It was producing `a.out` file. I just didn't see it, presuming that warning to be a compilation error. It worked. Thanks.